# MySQL replication slave losing connection each 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, ssh, replication

I have multiple servers set up with MySQL one-way replication for backup purposes. On one of these slaves I have a problem. Exactly each 10 minutes it loses connection and reconnects without problems. Example from error log:

```
121216 18:05:49 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log 'mysql-bin.000002' at position 782733912
121216 18:05:49 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:5002' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2013
121216 18:06:49 [Note] Slave: connected to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:5002',replication resumed in log 'mysql-bin.000002' at position 782733912
121216 18:15:49 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
121216 18:15:49 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log 'mysql-bin.000002' at position 822218944
121216 18:15:49 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:5002' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2013
121216 18:16:49 [Note] Slave: connected to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:5002',replication resumed in log 'mysql-bin.000002' at position 822218944
121216 18:25:49 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ( server_errno=2013)
121216 18:25:49 [Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log 'mysql-bin.000002' at position 850106111
121216 18:25:49 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error reconnecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:5002' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2013
```

So, everything works, but the error log is flooded with messages.

I looked at various MySQL settings, but I don't see any set to 10 minutes or 600 seconds.

FWIW, replication works through SSH tunnel using AutoSSH. I looked into sshd_config, but also do not see any timeout setting.

Which setting should I look into?

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at some similar problems lately and it turns out that our firewall blocks autossh monitoring port thus autossh restarts ssh every 10 mins. This may happen to you too.

Check your autossh log. It is usually /var/log/syslog unless you specifies AUTOSSH_LOGFILE

Comment: +1. Thanks for the idea. However, no firewall is active. iptables filter rules are empty.

Comment: Does it say anything in the log? 10-min is the default autossh poll time. http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh

Comment: This *has* to be the problem.  Googling "Reconnecting after a failed master event read down for 1 minute every 10 minutes" led me here... And as it turns out, we use `autossh` as well.  Will look into it and report.

Comment: Confirmed: It's `autossh`.  Further, it looks like omitting the `-M` parameter might fix the problem.  (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=351162)

Answer (score 0):

As @interskh pointed out, the culprit may be `ssh`.  My `/var/log/syslog` contained messages like the following:

```
Sep 15 16:34:57 servername autossh[2799]: timeout polling to accept read connection
Sep 15 16:34:57 servername autossh[2799]: port down, restarting ssh
Sep 15 16:34:57 servername autossh[2799]: starting ssh (count 136)
Sep 15 16:34:57 servername autossh[2799]: ssh child pid is 11664
```

I found a [Debian bug report thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=351162) that suggested that contrary to many tutorials, it isn't necessary to include the `-M` parameter.  Since version 1.4a-1, `autossh` will use a randomly selected "high" port by default (which is arguably better than manually specifying a monitoring port with `-M`).

**Omitting the `-M` flag solved the problem for me.**

Previous command (restarts the SSH connection every 10 minutes)

```
autossh -p2223 -M 20000 -f username@example.com -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

New (working) command

```
autossh -p2223 -f username@example.com -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

In case it helps anyone, our SSH client is running Ubuntu and the SSH server is running CentOS.